# dynamic addition and deletion of items to NavigationView menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

My application requires NavigationDrawer to be added / deleted with entries. At present it is working without any issue.

I would like to replace NavigationDrawer with NavigationView so that I get better look minimal code.

My current nav.drawer contains default entries followed by dynamically adding /deleting entries based on user requirement.

Entries are stored in db and populated in nav drawer whenever app is opened.

I am referring 
http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/

I came to know with 23.0.0 and 23.1.1.. etc, there is some issue with adding items dynamically. I also want dynamic deletion of entries from NavigationView

adding, deleting items in navigation view is possible ?

any sample i can refer to learn navigationview for above operations better?

Answer (score 4):

If you set your items in a menu (thing you should), you can add and remove menu items to that menu

```
NavigationView nav = (NavigationView)findViewById(nav_id);
Menu menu = nav.getMenu();
menu.removeItem(item_id);
menu.addItem(item_id);
```

In this quick introduction you can see how to set the menu items 
[Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2015/05/android-design-support-library.htmlhttp://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html?m=1)

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this? how to get / remove item_id?

Comment: Added a link for you, hope it helps